# Update express session through socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, session, express

I have a Node.js server using express framework with a session system. The program is a simple 1vs1 game. In order to play, a user can create a room and an other user can join it so the game can start. The room ID is stored into the user's session.

If you take a look at the following code, you'll see how I manage to access express sessions in a "socket code". This is great, it works. However, I cannot modify values in the session object.

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: 'my secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
});

var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use(sessionMiddleware);

io.use(function(socket, next) {
    sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // some stuff

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        socket.request.session.room = undefined; // this is not working
    });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Is there a way to do what I want or should I rethink the way rooms are managed ?

Thank you